# THREEJS videoTexture resolution/ streaks

Tags: javascript, three.js, videotexture

I created a videoTexture using THREEJS but when displaying it, it seems as there are streaks on the video.

```js
const video = document.getElementById('video');
const videoTexture = new THREE.VideoTexture(video)
videoTexture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;        
videoTexture.flipY = false;
```

I tried adding `magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;`but it didn't change anything.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxwsy.jpg) is the image of my video where we can see the streaks and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LoXt.jpg) is my original image without the streaks showing

Comment: Looks like it’s getting squished. Maybe try changing the minFilter?

Comment: @Marquizzo Thank you for your answer. I have tried using other minFilter but LinearFilter and NearestFilter are the only ones working, the other ones render only a black square, and it doesn't seem to solve my issue